# I'm releasing my software. Do I have to use .net obfuscator?

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I'm planning to release an alpha version of my freeware-closed source software shortly(It's an authoring tool written in C#), do I have to use .net obfuscator?

Generally i wouldn't like for people to effortlessly browse the code and - most importantly - modify it.

(I'm afraid, i'm not ready to opensource it at this point in time.)

If indeed i do need to use an obfuscator, would you suggest one what does a "good enough" job and preferably integrates itself with MS Visual Studio (obfuscates automatically on release builds)?

Comment: If it is freeware, why not just open source it from the beginning?

Comment: @Mentalikryst - Not all developers buy into the socialist ideas that all code should be open to everyone.

Comment: @Josh Einstein open source != no cost. Open source is about the right to view the source of an application regardless of whether you paid for it or not.

Comment: @wawa - I know, but also free != open source. I've released several free apps that I don't particularly feel obligated to release the source to.

Comment: @JBeurer Modifying the source is not effortless even without obfuscation. You'd have to recreate the whole application. Regarding suggestions for competent obfuscators, there are already several questions here on SO asking exactly this. :)

Comment: @Josh Einstein that's true. However, a lot of the more popular freeware apps (Linux and the g* applications like gcc) are open source. So suggesting that it be open-sourced isn't far out.

Comment: I don't see how open-source is beneficial for low budget/small-time developers.

Comment: @JBeurer It's not necessarily beneficial to the developer, but it is beneficial to the power user. Say I find a piece of software that does almost everything I want, if I have the source then I can add the missing features myself or change how existing ones work. I could even contribute changes back to the original author which would probably help them out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Help me choose .net obfuscator program ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278932/help-me-choose-net-obfuscator-program)

Comment: The frequency with which typical users add functionality is near DC. That's one of the most ridiculous (and common) arguments in favor of open source that I've heard. Programmers are a different matter, but I really don't like sharing source for most of my projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you obfuscate your code, then you will slow down and *possibly* dissuade anyone who might try to reverse engineer it.

If you don't, then you might as well make it open source.

It's your choice - you have nothing to lose by obfuscating it.

Dotfuscator Community Edition comes included with Visual Studio these days, and it'll do a basic job (though obviously you need to pay if you want all the bells and whistles) - or there are a number of free/shareware options if you search.

Comment: "If you don't, then you might as well make it open source." does this imply that disassembling .net assembly into a human readable source code in(C# or VisualBasic) using the proper tools are next to effortless? And does it mean that making changes is rather easy?

Comment: @JBeurer - There is a free tool called .Net Reflector which makes it possible for anyone to easily decompile your source code.  Obfuscation simply makes it harder to read the source, but not impossible to recreate.

Comment: Yeah. Just checked my assemblies using redgate's reflector. You definitely have to USE obfuscator. It's pretty much open source otherwise.

Comment: Don't forget about the Reflector plugins that make it possible to modify *compiled DLLs* - obfuscation will help, but you might also want to strong-name them.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother. Anyone who is going to go through that much trouble will figure out a way, and the rest of your users just want something that works and don't care or want to know what the code looks like.

That said, the community version of dotfuscator is very limited. I hear the pro version is good, but haven't played with it.

Comment: So who would be a typical user of an obfuscator? Software which contains some sort of "trade secrets"? Software containing algorithms dealing with national identification numbers and stuff like that? I have no sensitive things like that. I just wouldn't like my software to be modified and tinkered with.

Comment: Honestly, if your code contains some whiz-bang oh-my-lord-wow-that's-new-and-sweet way of doing something, I'd consider implementing at least that portion of it in non-managed code to make decompilation more difficult. CIL is inherently easy to disassemble. Obfuscators just add degrees of difficulty.

Comment: And, to answer your other question, it is incredibly unlikely that anyone will attempt to *distribute* a modified version of your app. Focus on building your application. If this becomes a problem in the future, solve it then.

Comment: I agree to what Jason said - there's nothing to lose by using obfuscation.  Moreover accessing source code is indeed pretty much effortless and it looks very close to the original if i don't use any obfuscation. Even basic obfuscation using dotfuscator community edition makes me at least feel like i'm not releasing source code along with the executable.

Comment: That's certainly your prerogative, and I agree with your point. I certainly don't want to *give away* my source. Having been in the position to reverse engineer several apps (legally - my client had lost the source when a former dev lost his mind), I can say it would have been a lot more difficult - though still not impossible - if some obfuscator had been used. Just depends on whether your app and market warrant the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use a obfuscator if you dont want others to see your code.

[Crypto Obfuscator](http://www.ssware.com/cryptoobfuscator/obfuscator-net.htm) can do the job well and also integrates with Visual Studio via MSBuild.